# How to use rowspan in td using dominate tags library?

Tags: python, dominate

As you can see in the code below, I am generating an HTML table with 4 columns. The first and second column have 1 row and the 3rd and 4th should have 5 rows.

I have tried using rowspan but cannot get it work and it gives weird output. Right now I am using a `table` element nested in the main `table` but I don't want to use that, I'd like to use `rowspan`

```
from dominate import tags as tags# import time, subprocess, os, datetime, zipfile, shutil

doc = dominate.document(title="whatever")
with doc:
    tags.style("body{font-family:Helvetica}")
    tags.style("h1{font-size:x-large}")
    tags.style("h2{font-size:large}")
    tags.style("table{border-collapse:collapse}")
    tags.style("th{font-size:small;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px;background-color:#DDD}")
    tags.style("td{font-size:small;text-align:center;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px}")   

    with tags.table():
                with tags.thead():
                    tags.th("Test")
                    tags.th("Pass%")
                    tags.th("random")
                    tags.th("Bugs / Notes")
                with tags.tbody():
                    with tags.tr():
                        tags.td("random")
                        tags.td("random", "%", style="font-size:small;text-align:center;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px;background-color:#66FF66")
                        with tags.td():
                            with tags.table(style = ""):
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                        with tags.td():
                            with tags.table():
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                                with tags.tr():
                                    tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")

HTML_TMP = "/tmp/demo.html"
MAIL_TMP = "/tmp/demo.txt"


# save it to a file
with open(HTML_TMP, "w") as f:
     f.write(str(doc))
```

Can you please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Please post a minimal, verifiable, complete example.
I'm unable to reproduce this because I do not have config and st.
If these are just random values, please replace these examples or define them in the code body.

Try reading here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the HTML structure, I think.  You want to remove the embedded tables from the main table and just give the first two cells in the first row the attribute `rowspan="5"`.  The below does this with minimal other changes to your code.

```
import dominate
from dominate import tags as tags# import time, subprocess, os, datetime, zipfile, shutil

doc = dominate.document(title="whatever")
with doc:
    tags.style("body{font-family:Helvetica}")
    tags.style("h1{font-size:x-large}")
    tags.style("h2{font-size:large}")
    tags.style("table{border-collapse:collapse}")
    tags.style("th{font-size:small;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px;background-color:#DDD}")
    tags.style("td{font-size:small;text-align:center;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px}")       
    with tags.table():
        with tags.thead():
            tags.th("Test")
            tags.th("Pass%")
            tags.th("random")
            tags.th("Bugs / Notes")
        with tags.tbody():
            with tags.tr(): #Row 1
                tags.td("random", rowspan="5")
                tags.td("random", "%", rowspan="5", style="font-size:small;text-align:center;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px;background-color:#66FF66")
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
            with tags.tr(): # Row 2 (only cols 3 and 4)
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
            with tags.tr(): # Row 3
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
            with tags.tr(): # Row 4
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
            with tags.tr(): # Row 5
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")
                tags.td("1", style = "font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px")


HTML_TMP = "/tmp/demo.html"
MAIL_TMP = "/tmp/demo.txt"


# save it to a file
with open(HTML_TMP, "w") as f:
     f.write(str(doc))
```

The resulting HTML and output are below (hit unhide, then run code snippet to see results):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>whatever</title>
  </head>
  <body><style>body{font-family:Helvetica}</style><style>h1{font-size:x-large}</style><style>h2{font-size:large}</style><style>table{border-collapse
:collapse}</style><style>th{font-size:small;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px;background-color:#DDD}</style><style>td{font-size:small;text-align:cen
ter;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px}</style>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Pass%</th>
        <th>random</th>
        <th>Bugs / Notes</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="5">random</td>
          <td rowspan="5" style="font-size:small;text-align:center;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px;background-color:#66FF66">random%</td>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
          <td style="font-size:small;text-align:center;padding:4px">1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note** that you could do further tidy up by adding repeated code into a function and calling that, but I'm guessing that this is a placeholder code and you won't actually be adding exactly the same info in each cell